# Spring error 404 when trying to access MyController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I am new to Spring. I am trying to integrate Spring in a section of a web app.
It has to work with urls like :

```
http://localhost:9080/myfolder/myspring
```

My **web.xml** includes:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>    
    /WEB-INF/config/myspring-context.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>       

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/springviews</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**applicationContext.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

        <!-- registers all of Spring's standard post-processors for annotation-based configuration -->
        <context:annotation-config />

        <tx:annotation-driven/>
        <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>

       <bean id="properties" class="springcop.pojo.TestObject">

        </bean>

    </beans>
```

my **myspring-context.xml** is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="springcop"/>

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

 <!-- Resolve logical view names to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/springviews/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>



</beans>
```

And here is **MyController**

```
package springcop;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyController {


    public MyController () {
         System.out.println("--->GestioneController");

    }


     @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String test() {
         System.out.println("--->test");
         return "test";
     }

}
```

The up is runniong without errors. Spring seems to work as I have printed out in my log  "--->GestioneController which is in the constructor of my COntroller.

Anyway, when I open in the browser

```
http://localhost:9080/myfolder/myspring/test
```

to execute the test method in MyController I get 404 error.

What's should I do to make it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the name of your webapp is `myfolder` as listed in the question, the url would be...

```
http://localhost:9080/myfolder/springviews/test
```

The problem is you have the dispatcher servlet mapped to springviews.  You need to map the dispatcher servlet as follows in web.xml...

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/<url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Edit:**  Also, you have put your spring configuration in a context-param, but you did not add the listener to pick it up.  Add the following to your web.xml....

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks @hyness I will test it tomorrow and let you know. Is value = "/test" correct in RequestMapping ?

Comment: Hello @hyness, I have modified as you suggested but 404 error and this in the log: PageNotFound W org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myfolder/springviews/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: I've updated my answer, if this still doesn't answer your issue then you need to post the full files not just portions along with any error messages from the logs.  If it does fix your issue, please mark the answer as accepted.